# Definition for rule 'simple-import-sort/sort' was not found

Tags: node.js, reactjs, eslint, typescript-eslint

I'm using react with the simple-import-sort eslint plugin. I think my `.eslintrc.js` is right, but I'm not able to make this specific plugin work. I get the following errors at the first line of my files:

> `Definition for rule 'simple-import-sort/sort' was not found  simple-import-sort/sort`

Here's my config:

```
module.exports = {
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'airbnb-typescript',
    'airbnb/hooks',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking',
    'plugin:import/recommended',
    'plugin:jest/recommended',
    'plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'prettier',
    'prettier/@typescript-eslint',
    'prettier/react',
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: 'module',
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    project: './tsconfig.json',
  },
  ignorePatterns: ['*.js'],
  plugins: ['react', 'prettier', 'import', 'simple-import-sort'],
  rules: {
    'prettier/prettier': ['error'],
    'no-underscore-dangle': 'off',
    'no-async-promise-executor': 'warn',
    'no-unused-vars': 'error',
    'object-shorthand': ["error", "always"],
    'react/destructuring-assignment': ['off', 'never'],
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': ['warn', { extensions: ['.tsx', '.js', '.jsx'] }],
    'react/jsx-uses-react': 'error',
    'react/jsx-uses-vars': 'error',
    'react/no-unescaped-entities': 'off',
    'react/jsx-no-undef': ['error', { allowGlobals: true }],
    'react/jsx-props-no-spreading': 'warn',
    'react/prop-types': 'off',
    'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps': 'off',

    'sort-imports': 'off',
    'simple-import-sort/sort': 'error',
    'import/order': 'off',
    'import/prefer-default-export': 'off',
    'import/extensions': 'off',
    'import/no-extraneous-dependencies': ['error', { devDependencies: true }],

    // '@typescript-eslint/camelcase': ['error', { properties: 'never' }],
    '@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': 'off',
    'jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid': 'off',
    'jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions': 'off',
  },
};
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It may be that you're using v6.

It looks like v6 doesn't have a `simple-import-sort/sort` rule, see [usage in the README](https://github.com/lydell/eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort#usage). This was a [change from v5 on Nov 15](https://github.com/lydell/eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort/blob/v6.0.0/CHANGELOG.md#version-600-2020-11-15).

You probably need to make the following change:

```
- 'simple-import-sort/sort': 'error',
+ 'simple-import-sort/imports': 'error',
```

Answer (score 3):

Form Version 6.0.0 of eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort:

1. Renamed: simple-import-sort/sort is now called
   simple-import-sort/imports.
2. Added: simple-import-sort/exports for
   sorting (some) exports.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "simple-import-sort/imports": "error",
    "simple-import-sort/exports": "error"
  }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 3):

I also had to add "simple-import-sort" to "plugins" in .eslintrc:

```
{
  "plugins": ["simple-import-sort"]
}
```

and then it got rid of the errors.